# sed : add a string in specific line

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I want to add a string in particular place in a paragraph

that is:

```
$rcmail_config['default_host'] = '';
```

to

```
$rcmail_config['default_host'] = 'abcdef';
```

Is it possible using sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make:

```
sed -i "s/\$rcmail_config\['default_host'\] =.*/\$rcmail_config['default_host'] = 'abcdef';/" /your.file
```

It will replace only the line, and set your data regardless of what previously.

Comment: use group to simplify the replace pattern (avoid error and more easy to read)

Answer (score 1):

`sed -e "/\$rcmail_config/s/'';$/'abcdef';/"` should do what you want.

```
> echo -e "foo = '';\nbar = '';\n\$rcmail_config['default_host'] = '';"
foo = '';
bar = '';
$rcmail_config['default_host'] = '';

> echo -e "foo = '';\nbar = '';\n\$rcmail_config['default_host'] = '';" | sed -e "/\$rcmail_config/s/'';$/'abcdef';/"
foo = '';
bar = '';
$rcmail_config['default_host'] = 'abcdef';
```

Comment: assuming there is only one $rcmail_config in the file (certainly the case)

Comment: Granted. More but I can't restrict more given what the OP wrote.